# Success in running appium code from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, appium

Has anyone successfully able to run appium test from Android Studio ? I would appreciate if you could pass on to me a working sample of it.

I have been trying to get the setup running for over two weeks now. On trying to run test the build fails at preDexDebug step with below error

```
trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class"
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library. This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality. If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the \"--core-library\" option to suppress this error message.
.......... and the error goes on.
```

I tried using the --core-library option. however the error still persists.

I am making use of maven to gather the dependencies for appium.

```
compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.2.0'
```

**My primary question**: is appium and its dependencies compatible to run with Android Studio? Because it runs pretty smooth on Eclipse

Commenting *io.appium* dependency solve the mentioned build error, but I have to comment my tests.

After exhausting my own knowledge, I read a couple of posts on stackoverflow and other internet resources around my problem, but there is no concrete solution. It is more of a hit-and-try mechanism saying "this might work". I tried them, but with no success.

Hence, I would like to know

1. Firstly, if appium and its dependencies work very well with Android Studio
2. A zip of working solution (if possible)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: 1. I hope you understand that Android Studio is just an IDE - smart text editor. You could write the code in Notepad and it still would work if written correctly.
Appium is a standalone Selenium WebDriver wrapper framework to be used for mobile devices.
2. No. Web is full of examples - trust me.
3. It seems that your application is no building correctly. Appium has no dependency to `"javax/xml/XMLConstants.class"`.

Comment: I have been using android studio to write scripts for appium and had no problem. Which framework you are using? I am using gradle and it works fine.

Comment: @Gaurav i am using gradle

Comment: @KristapsMežavilks even i agree appium has no dependency on XMLConstants.class. Still the build fails at this point. 
I am creating a blank activity, adding a simple text field and later referring to io.appium library in gradle file. the build fails.

Comment: @Gaurav, i was able to resolve most of the errors. i did reset of AndroidStudio by deleting couple of folders under ~Library/Application Support/. i guess i did some misconfigurations while learning AndroidStudio.
i have finally ended at Dex 64K limit error. Did you also face this ? I know this is solvable either by splitting the dex file or using Proguard.
My point is just for a small test app this limit is reached. I am worried when I use appium on a real application.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for `Appium Setup` in `Android Studio`:

1. Download - Android Studio Appium Java Client Selenium Client Library Appium Server Install Java
2. Install Android Studio please follow the steps given in the link to
3. Install android studio step by step on windows machine click here After installation of android studio ,open android studio and create a new project - How to create android project?
4. Add the downloaded Appium jars into your project - click on project -> click on app->copy all the jars in lib. Select the copied    jars except Selenium, Java client and Junit Jar ,then right click on    it and click on "Add as Library".
5. Click on build.gradle in app you will see all the libs added like below screenshot add junit:4.12.Sync the project or Re-build the    project. It should show "Build Successful Message"
6. Now you are ready to write your first test case - right click on the package and click on "Create Java Class". Copy given test case    sample.
7. Running the Test case-
      Click on build variant Select Unit Testing Start the appium server with Specific port "4444"click here Connect device with USB    debugging on or start an emulator. Right click on the test class and    click on "Run"

This steps for taken from this [post](http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/01/setting-up-appium-with-android-studio.html) and [video](https://youtu.be/n8QqYAXKWEU).